# Does fsck.mode=force in GRUB overrides 6th column option in fstab?

Tags: boot, grub, systemd, fstab, fsck

I set `fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes` against `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` file. Will this option override numbers set in the 6th column of `/etc/fstab`? For example, will my root partition still be checked and repaired if necessary even though I have set `0` to the 6th column of `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, all that the option does is cause systemd to pass the `-f` option to `fsck`. It has no effect on the output of systemd-fstab-generator (where the 'pass' column is parsed).

(The `-f` option is passed through to the filesystem-specific fsck program; in fsck.ext4 it means "Force checking even if the file system seems clean".

Similarly, `fsck.repair=yes` adds the `-y` option; `fsck.repair=preen` adds `-a`.)